# Convexity of Hilbert cube

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I am trying to show that the Hilbert cube $\{ x_n \in l^2(\mathbb{N}) \mid  x_n \in [0, \frac{1}{n}] \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is convex and (norm)-compact.

Comment: The triangle inequality should give square summability of a convex combination of 2 square summable sequences. Maybe take $\epsilon$ balls the sequences $1/n$ with only one coordinate set to zero to get a countable covering, then maybe there is a finite subcover?

Answer (score 0):

To show that the cube is convex, what happens with $\lambda x + (1- \lambda)y$ if $x,y \in [0,a]$ and $\lambda \in [0,1]$?

For compactness, as $[0,\frac{1}{n}]$ is compact for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the space $X=[0,1] \times [0, \frac{1}{2}] \times [0,\frac{1}{3} ] \times \cdots$ is compact in the product topology. Then you can construct a continuous function from $X$ to the Hilbert cube, and deduce that the Hilbert cube is compact.